# Release on TouchEvent not working

Tags: java, android, touch

Here is my method code I use in onTouchEvent:

```
public void touch(MotionEvent event) {
    // starta = "klicka för att börja";

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        starta = "Click to start";
        fN.aktivitetNer.start();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            if (y == -300) {
                touch(event);
            }

            else if (y > -300) {
                fN.aktivitetNer.interrupt();
                fU.aktivitetUpp.start();
                p++;
            }
        }

        else if (y2 <= y + xMax) {
            fN.aktivitetNer.interrupt();
            fU.aktivitetUpp.start();
            p = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What should happening is a knife coming down very fast with help of a Thread(fN.aktivitetNer) and if the knife slice the finger(y2) you loose, if you're fast enough you score one point(p), when you loose or win the knife will go up again with another Thread(fU.aktivitetUpp)
I know it's not perfect but it's now working at all!
ps. if you click two times on the screen the programm will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Well it certainly won't work in it's current form, because the code will never enter your second if statement.

Your first if statement asserts that `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.  If this is true, then at`event.getAction()` cannot possibly be equal to `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` and you will never enter that block of code.

Since I don't know what your thread does I can't be certain, but you probably want something more like this:

```
public void touch(MotionEvent event)
{
    // starta = "klicka för att börja";

    int actionCode = event.getAction();
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        //Start to drop knife
    }

    else if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        if (Knife is falling, and touch point is below knife)
        {
            //Add one to score
        }
        else if (Knife is falling, and touch point is above knife)
        {
            //Reset score to 0
        }

    }

    else if (Knife has already fallen and still touching screen)
    {
        //Reset score to 0
    }
}
```

Comment: It still not working :( The points does't work and I can stil not click two times on the screen without it crash... And one wierd thing too, " start = "click to begin" " doesn't become visible at once, it become visivle when the thread start(it start 5-10 second after the click)